# Can we pass value and annotation of method parameters

Tags: java, reflection, rest-assured

To manage swagger documentations I am using custom annotations for the methods which call the API

```
@SwagRef(method = POST, url = "/my/api/{pathParam1}")
  public Response callMyAPI(
      @MyParam(name = "pathParam1", required = true, in = PATH) String p1,
      @MyParam(name = "param2", required = false, in = QUERY) String p2) {
    return given()
            .pathParam("pathParam1", p1)
            .queryParam("param2", p2)
            .get();
  }
```

There is a separate piece of code which validates the Swagger/api/docs vs the annotations.
However I'm wondering is it possible to somehow use all this already presented data in the annotations and have a common code where I can pass the method reference or the parameter reference and the RequestSpecification can be built using the annotations.

I tried with reflection, but I'm unable to fetch the value of parameters using reflection from method

I was only able to deduce the method type and API since it's constant using the methodName and stackTrace

```
    private SwagRef defineSwaggerInfo() {
        List<StackTraceElement> stackTrace = asList(currentThread().getStackTrace());
        return stackTrace.stream()
            .map(tryOrNull(element -> Pair.with(element.getMethodName(), forName(element.getClassName()))))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(pair -> MyAPI.class.isAssignableFrom(pair.getValue1()))
            .map(pair -> with(pair.getValue0(), asList(pair.getValue1().getDeclaredMethods())))
            .flatMap(
                tryOrNull(
                    pair ->
                        pair.getValue1().stream()
                            .filter(method -> Objects.equals(method.getName(), pair.getValue0()))
                            .peek(method -> method.setAccessible(true))
                            .map(method -> method.getAnnotation(SwagRef.class))))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();
}
```

But I'm not able to come up with a generic function for Building the request spec using method parameters

I tried looking at AspectJ but wasn't able to embed it properly

Comment: Can you replace that pseudo code with real code showing how you get from a `getStackTrace()` to something you can call `getAnnotation(SwagRef.class)` on?

Comment: Sure, but it's just to refer to what I'm able to do. I'm able to get the url and method ref from the annotated Method since it's constant but I'm unable to pass and get the values of the parameters with help of their annotations when the function is called to possibly create a generic RequestSpecification Builder

Comment: Well, seeing the actual code helps understanding what you are doing. Note that 1) your code could end up at the wrong method when there are multiple method with the same name, 2) `setAccessible(true)` is obsolete 3) instead of `.map(method -> method.getAnnotation(SwagRef.class)))` you probably want to use `filter(method -> method.hasAnnotation(SwagRef.class)))` to keep the `Method` object as otherwise, you won’t have access to the `@MyParam` annotations 4) if “parameters” refers to the actual parameter values are not available via Reflection

Comment: Thanks, I know the drawback this code has with multiple function names, to that end we're maintaining the code so it only has the annotation on the function which actually calls API and not the overloaded methods.
Yes, the filter part is a good suggestion, should've done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get the actual parameter values from the stack via Reflection. In fact, there’s not even a guaranty that the parameter values of an ongoing invocation are still on the stack at that point.

The closest you can get to perform automated parameter processing, is to declare the methods in an interface and generate a [proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html):

```
interface FrontEnd {
    public static FrontEnd get() {
        return (FrontEnd)Proxy.newProxyInstance(FrontEnd.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{FrontEnd.class}, (proxy, method, args) -> {
                if(method.getDeclaringClass() == Object.class) {
                    switch(method.getName()) {
                        case "toString": return
                            FrontEnd.class.getName()+'@'+System.identityHashCode(proxy);
                        case "equals": return proxy == args[0];
                        case "hashCode": return System.identityHashCode(proxy);
                        default: throw new AssertionError();
                    }
                }
                SwagRef swagRef = method.getAnnotation(SwagRef.class);
                if(swagRef == null) throw new IncompatibleClassChangeError();
                MyParam[] p = Arrays.stream(method.getParameterAnnotations())
                    .map(pa -> Arrays.stream(pa)
                        .filter(a -> a.annotationType() == MyParam.class)
                        .findFirst().orElseThrow(
                            () -> new IllegalStateException("missing required @MyParam")))
                    .toArray(MyParam[]::new);
                Map<String,String> map = IntStream.range(0, args.length).boxed()
                    .filter(i -> p[i].required() || args[i] != null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> p[i].name(), i -> args[i].toString()));
                // do actual invocation logic here
                System.out.println(
                    "operation: "+swagRef.method()+' '+swagRef.url()+", "+map);
                return null;
        });
    }

    @SwagRef(method = POST, url = "/my/api/{pathParam1}")
    public Response callMyAPI(
        @MyParam(name = "pathParam1", required = true, in = PATH) String p1,
        @MyParam(name = "param2", required = false, in = QUERY) String p2);
}
```

You may add more methods to that interface, to be handled the same way, assuming that they all have the necessary annotations.

Starting with Java 9, you can use a `private` method in the `interface`, which I would prefer here.

```
interface FrontEnd {
    public static FrontEnd get() {
        return (FrontEnd)Proxy.newProxyInstance(FrontEnd.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{FrontEnd.class}, FrontEnd::callImpl);
    }
    @SwagRef(method = POST, url = "/my/api/{pathParam1}")
    public Response callMyAPI(
        @MyParam(name = "pathParam1", required = true, in = PATH) String p1,
        @MyParam(name = "param2", required = false, in = QUERY) String p2);

    private static Object callImpl(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
        if(method.getDeclaringClass() == Object.class) {
            switch(method.getName()) {
                case "toString": return
                    FrontEnd.class.getName()+'@'+System.identityHashCode(proxy);
                case "equals": return proxy == args[0];
                case "hashCode": return System.identityHashCode(proxy);
                default: throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
        SwagRef swagRef = method.getAnnotation(SwagRef.class);
        if(swagRef == null) throw new IncompatibleClassChangeError();
        MyParam[] p = Arrays.stream(method.getParameterAnnotations())
            .map(pa -> Arrays.stream(pa)
                .filter(a -> a.annotationType() == MyParam.class)
                .findFirst().orElseThrow(
                    () -> new IllegalStateException("missing required @MyParam")))
            .toArray(MyParam[]::new);
        Map<String,String> map = IntStream.range(0, args.length).boxed()
            .filter(i -> p[i].required() || args[i] != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> p[i].name(), i -> args[i].toString()));
        // do actual invocation logic here
        System.out.println("operation: "+swagRef.method()+' '+swagRef.url()+", "+map);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may split up the logic between the interface and a, possibly non-public, helper class.

Comment: This works absolutely like charm, there is one drawback though.
With this, I have to invoke callMyAPI only through the initialised proxy Interface which stops me from plugging this to the hierarchy that I have with classes holding the API methods.

It'll take some refactoring to bridge this gap

Would you say that using AspectJ on any annotated methods can do something ?

Comment: I have no experience with AspectJ, but I can imagine that it has something that helps.

Comment: It can be used to essentially intercept an execution point with a lot of possible parameters (including annotations). It essentially works like a python tag (annotations) which are a charm for such type of tasks, but alas, java doesn't work that way. I'll try to post a solution which works best, with either AspectJ or this. Thanks